# how to display number in two digits

Tags: php

I want to select names which expires in this month and two months ahead.

```
  $t=date('Y');

  $q = date('m');

 for($e=$q;$e<=($q+2);$e++){
 $ren = $t.'-'.$e;
 $sql = "select name,renewal_date from hosting_details where renewal_date LIKE '$ren%' ";

}
```

In this first month display correctly but then onward doesn't give any result. when i echo $ren,for the first month it gives 2016-01 and second month 2016-2.
how can i resolve this

Comment: Take a look at `sprintf()`

Comment: i want the results to be 2016-02, 2016-03,2016-04,.......... but i get as 2016-2, 2016-3,2016-4,..........

Comment: BTW, what is your query going to do in December? (Spoiler: `2016-12`, `2016-13`, `2016-14` - I don't think it's likely that you'll find *those* months in the calendar)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `sprintf()` to format the numbers.  For example:

```
$t=date('Y');
$q = date('m');

for($e=$q;$e<=($q+2);$e++){
  $ren = $t.'-'. sprintf("%'.02d", $e);
  var_dump($ren);
}
```

More info on `sprintf()` can be found [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

However since you're working with dates, why not use a \DateTime object and have it do the work for you?  This means you don't have to do any date overflow logic etc - PHP does all the complex work for you! :)  e.g.

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2016-01-11' );
$numMonths = 2;
for($i=0; $i<$numMonths; $i++)
{
    // e.g. increment the month and format the date.
    var_dump($begin->modify( '+1 month' )->format("Y-m-d"));

    // of course modify the format to "Y-m" for your code:
    // $ren = $begin->modify( '+1 month')->format("Y-m");
}
```

For more reading you can checkout \DateTime and [\DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) in the PHP docs.

Here's a [working example](https://3v4l.org/9nh7j) comparing the two approaches.

Comment: Oops, sorry; I was typing faster than I was thinking.

Comment: I reverted the edit to `+1 month` @Piskvor; using `+ $i month` would incrementally add one, two then three months.  See the live 3v4l.org link I added at the bottom of the answer for a working example using +1 month.

Answer (score 0):

Using sprintf() can solve your problem:

```
$t=date('Y');
$q = date('m');

for($e=$q;$e<=($q+2);$e++){
  $ren = sprintf('%d-%02d', $t,$e);
  $sql = "select name,renewal_date from hosting_details where renewal_date LIKE '$ren%' ";
  echo $sql . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
select name,renewal_date from hosting_details where renewal_date LIKE '2016-01%' 
select name,renewal_date from hosting_details where renewal_date LIKE '2016-02%' 
select name,renewal_date from hosting_details where renewal_date LIKE '2016-03%'
```

Comment: I hesitate to upvote a solution which does *exactly* what the OP asked for, but will fail spectacularly in 11 months.

Comment: Conpletely valid objection but the problem of formating numbers gets addressed and that is what OP asked for. Sometimes you have to learn step by step.

Comment: It's a bit of a philosophical problem: "How do I shoot myself in the foot?" ;)